# Screen brightness keeps going to max

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

**My system**

I'm running a 13" retina MacBook Pro and using El Capitan 10.11.6.

Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 4 MB
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP111.0142.B00
  SMC Version (system): 2.16f68

**Issue**

Often while working in a low ambient light environment, I'll turn down the screen brightness to make the display more comfortable to work with. Several times, immediately after turning down the brightness, the system will raise it up to max again.

I turn it down.

The system turns it up.

This goes on for several minutes and continually interrupts/blinds me.

My Display settings allow automatic brightness adjustment. But this is in a room often with no lighting other than the laptop so it should be adjusting down if anything.

Even after turning this setting off and closing System Preferences, the brightness still is changing automatically. I have also tried resetting the System Management Controller (SMC).

How do I a) prevent this from happening and b) actually turn off automatic brightness adjustment?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common bug. 
You should consider contacting [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/contact) or taking it to an Apple store.

Comment: Are you implying it's a software bug or what? I won't be anywhere within 12+ hours travel of an Apple Store for the foreseeable future and Apple Support have been useless.